# Backing up and restoring power plan with C#

Tags: c#, cmd, powercfg

I making a program that messes around with the Windows power plan.
Before making any changes it would be wise to make a copy of the current power plan, so the user can restore it.
There is a command prompt command `powercfg –restoredefaultschemes` but it restores all plans and the user might have some settings that he set manually and I don't want him to lose it. So the only option is to export and then import.

So, as soon as the program starts, I use this code to create a backup of the current scheme if it does not exist:

```
if (!File.Exists(@".\\PowerPlan.pow"))   
        {
            var cmd = new Process { StartInfo = { FileName = "powercfg" } };
            using (cmd)
            {
                cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                cmd.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

                cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/export PowerPlan.pow SCHEME_CURRENT"; //saves to the current folder, provide path if needed.
                cmd.Start();
                MessageBox.Show("Profile saved");
            }
        }
```

In this case, we can use `SCHEME_CURRENT`to refer to the scheme that we need to export, without even using GUID.

Importing the profile back is easy as well with

```
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/-import PowerPlan.pow";
cmd.Start();
```

However, to actually restore the backed up power plan we need to not just import, but also set it as active.
When we changing something in the current power plan and want to set it as active, we can simply use

```
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/setactive SCHEME_CURRENT";
cmd.Start();
```

But when the power plan that we backed up just was imported, we can't use `SCHEME_CURRENT`(since the current is a modified one), and we don't know the GUID of the imported plan to reference it and set it as active.

**Is anybody has an idea of how it can be implemented without knowing GUID? Also, if someone sees a better way to backup/restore power plans I would be glad to hear your ideas and will be very thankful.**

Comment: the import command takes an optional GUID parameter which you can generate by yourself and pass to the command, and then later use that GUID to active

Comment: An application coded in C# does not need to run `%SystemRoot%\System32\powercfg.exe` which uses the functions of `%SystemRoot%\System32\powerprof.dll`. A C# coded application can use these functions directly using [powrprof.h header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/powrprof/) and its functions.